# How to translate text in shipping-estimation.html

Tags: magento2, localisation, knockout, i18n, internationalization

I need to translate the text **Enter your billing address to get a tax estimate.** in **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\cart\shipping-estimation.html**

It is a text showing in the cart

```
<form method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
    <fieldset class="fieldset estimate">
        <legend class="legend">
            <span data-bind="text: isVirtual ? $t('Estimate Tax') : $t('Estimate Shipping and Tax') "></span>
        </legend><br>
        <p class="field note" data-bind="text: isVirtual ? $t('Enter your billing address to get a tax estimate.') : $t('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.')"></p>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-fieldsets') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I added the translation in **app\design\frontend\company\base\i18n\de_DE.csv**:

```
"Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.", "Bitte geben Sie Ihren Ort an um eine Versandkostenschätzung zu erhalten."
```

and cleared the cache, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution that works for me at least.

My translation file is in:

```
app/design/frontend/**MyPackage**/**MyTheme**/i18n/XX_XX.csv
```

I added the string there.

Then I copied this file to my theme folder:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-estimation
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/**Yourpackage**/**Yourtheme**/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/shipping-estimation.html
```

Then I flushed all caches and manually deleted this file (I'm in developer mode):

```
pub/static/frontend/**Yourpackage**/**Yourtheme**/XX_XX/js-translation.json
```

When I refreshed the frontend checkout page the string was translated.

Comment: The solution is to clear the folder **pub/static/frontend/**, you don't need a copy of the template in your theme. I solved it by executing `grunt clean` and clearing the cache.

Comment: Ok. Have to try that. Maybe I missed that... I ran to this problem myself today. Thanks for the info.

Comment: When I follow these steps my styling is changing just for the part I translated